# Is it possible to affect the same variable of two different objects of the same class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, variables

Say I have a class:

```
class LiveEntity
{
public:
    int example = 5;
};
```

Now, in my main file I have two objects of that class:

```
LiveEntity Box[7];
Box->example = 0;

LiveEntity Circle[7];
Circle->example = 2;
```

Is there a way for me to alter both Circle->example and Box->example without having to write them separately? Say I wanted both of them to += a certain increment every frame, without having to write them individually one by one inside a for loop. In my actual main.cpp, I have about 10 different objects of the "LiveEntity" class, and I want all of them to be affected by the same addition.

Basically, currently, it looks like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++){
    Box[x].example += increment;
    Circle[x].example += increment;
    // and 8 more.
}
```

Comment: _"Is there a way..."_ no. And this is not C.

Comment: Did you try static protected field?

Comment: I wrote an answer about making `example` static, but I now realize it probably won't make sense to do such a thing in this case. If you don't want the member to be shared between all instances (you want every instance to have it's own `example` value), there is no other way than to modify every instance manually.

Comment: You have fourteen `LiveEntity` objects, not two, and using `->` to access the first element of an array is very misleading.

Comment: Unless `Box` and `Circle` point at the *same* object, there is no way.   If they (or their addresses) are elements on a container, it would be possible to loop over all elements of that container and do the same operation.   But that's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for (LiveEntity *arr : {Box, Circle})
        arr[i].example += increment;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a workaround (possibility) with [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

class LiveEntity {
public:
    int example = 5;
    //we need a default and for convenience an implicit value constructor
    LiveEntity(int val = 5) noexcept : example(val) {}
    //to avoid the implementation of each operator
    //we implement user-defined conversion methods
    operator int  () const noexcept { return example; }
    operator int& ()       noexcept { return example; }
};

//if no user-defined conversion was implemented,
//each operator has to be implemented 
//@see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith2#Notes
LiveEntity& operator += (LiveEntity& lhs, LiveEntity rhs) noexcept
{
    lhs.example += rhs.example;
    return lhs;
}

int main()
{
    //valarray instead of array
    std::valarray<LiveEntity> arr(5);

    //print the default instantiated elements
    for (auto e : arr) {
        std::cout << e.example << std::endl;
    }

    //increase by 1
    //without implicit value constructor,
    //something like arr += LiveEntity(1) has to be used
    arr += 1;

    //print the incremented values
    for (auto e : arr) {
        std::cout << e.example << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define a static member variable to store all the instance of the class, and define a function to update them one by one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class LiveEntity
{
public:
    LiveEntity() { instances_.insert(this); }
    ~LiveEntity() { instances_.erase(this); }

public:
    int example = 5;

public:
    static void IncrAll(int v)
    {
        for (auto instance : instances_)
            instance->example += v;
    }

public:
    static set<LiveEntity*> instances_;
    
};

set<LiveEntity*> LiveEntity::instances_;

void Test()
{
    LiveEntity le1;
    LiveEntity le2;
    LiveEntity le3;

    le1.example += 1;
    le2.example += 2;
    le3.example += 3;

    cout << le1.example << " " << le2.example << " " << le3.example << endl;    // 6 7 8

    LiveEntity::IncrAll(3);

    cout << le1.example << " " << le2.example << " " << le3.example << endl;    // 9 10 11
}


int main()
{
    cout << LiveEntity::instances_.size() << endl;

    Test();

    cout << LiveEntity::instances_.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```